# Ansible tower survey transforming survey string values

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

I currently pass parameters to my script which an ansible tower job template/role calls. In order to make it more user friendly, I have decided to use a survey to do this. The script takes on filenames as parameters.

The script accepts the parameters in this format

```
'file1.txt','file2.txt','file3.txt'
```

However, here is the problem

The file could be one, it could be 2 or three up to possibly 5.

I have thought about a solution and I think the best design is to have a comma delimited list of files coming from ansible survey, for example `file1, file2, file3`

How can I have a logic whereby with the list of files, they can be split and a loop used to copy them one by one if there are more than one file provided in the list, then have a variable that will add single quotes and a comma to the file list. For example in the survey the values provided such as `file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt` will then be transformed into a variable which contains the following

```
'file1.txt','file2.txt','file3.txt'
```

The other issue is this.

The ansible role copies the given file name onto a directory, I know the split function can be used to split a comma separated list, how can I then copy them onto a folder in a loop ? If we look at the example below, it only works for a single file.

EDIT.

I have looked at the split function and combining it with a loop. I get an error when I run it. Template error while templating string

```
---

- name: Set file name
  set_fact:
  file1: "file1.txt"
  file_list: "file1.txt"


- name: Set working directory
  set_fact:
  standard_path: "{{ansible_user_dir}}\\execution"
  content_file: "{{standard_path}}\\{{file1}}"

- name: Copy file to working directory
  win_copy:
    src: "file1.txt"
    dest: "{{content_file}}"

- name: Set parameters for script
  set_fact:
    params: "-filenames '{{content_file}}'"


- name: Run a loop to copy the files.
  win_copy:
    src: "{{ item }}"
    dest: "{{standard_path \\ item }}"
  with_items: "{{file_list.split(',') }}"
```

Comment: The multiple choice survey type returns a list. You can loop on that to copy and use the `join` filter to create your parameter string.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have edited the question to use a single text field and provide a comma delimited list of files. this will be easier to transform based on my research.

Comment: The text survrey type returns a string. `your_var.split(',')` that string to get a list then go back to the second part of my first comment.

Comment: Please do you have an example as I have searched online to find how to use a split and loop.

Comment: I already gave a split example. Loops have [an entire dedicated page](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html) in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the code to test out the split. it splits out the values which is fine, I then thought i could use this within a loop using with_items, its giving me an error above.

Comment: The error is not in the loop but in dest. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @Zeitounator I figured out the issue and fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

---

The section within the code that was throwing an exception has now been fixed.
The jinja2 standard requires the variables to be in separate {{}} as seen below.

```
- name: Run a loop to copy the files.
  win_copy:
    src: "{{ item }}"
    dest: "{{standard_path}}\\{{item }}"
  with_items: "{{file_list.split(',') }}"
```